# Probability Question dice

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

[image]

for the first part, I think its £10.50? Can anyone help me with the second part? thank you.

Comment: How you deduced $£10.50$?

Comment: Tell us how did you get £10.50.

Comment: 6+ 5+4+3+2+1 = 21 /2 = 10.5

Comment: You have to divide by 6.

Comment: Why do you divide by $2$? And please add your work to the question, instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: oh, so its 3.5? can you help with the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the notion of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) to tackle such kind of questions.

Let $X$ be the amount of money that he will get after rolling the dice.

(i) $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^6 i\cdot\frac{1}{6} = 3.5$. Since the chance to play the game will cost him $£1$, he should expect to win $£3.5-£1=£2.5$ on average.

(ii) It makes sense try to roll the dice for the second time if the number of points that he received from the first attempt is less than expected average, so $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot6 + \frac{1}{6}\cdot5 + \frac{1}{6}\cdot4 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot3.5 = 4.25$. We should subtract $£1$ as a price for the game again.